# Android: Change correct to UI Mode dark in Android 10 and greater

Tags: android, android-10.0, android-dark-theme

I would like to apply the Dark mode to my app for Android 10 and greater.
Therefore I wrote following code on startup:

```
int modeNight;
int colorMode = getResources().getConfiguration().uiMode & Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_MASK;
if (colorMode == Configuration.UI_MODE_NIGHT_YES) {
    modeNight = AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES;
} else {
    modeNight = AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO;
}

AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(modeNight);
```

This works in general. If I start the app, the correct mode gets set.
But, this does not work if the app is still in the background and I start it again.
If I start the app while it is not completely closed `getResources().getConfiguration()` does not get updated and it always returns the old value until I kill the app and start it again.
How can I force the app to reload the resources configuration? Or how else can I fix that problem?

**Update**:
I now replaced `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(modeNight);` with `setTheme(R.style.Theme_ImmoFinder24);`.
This works for the general Theme, but I still have a problem:
I've got some elements (Recycler Views) where the user can set the background color. One color for the normal mode and one for the Dark mode.
The theme changes, but the color listens to the value set in `AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(modeNight);`.
If I keep both `setDefaultNightMode()` and `setTheme(R.style.Theme_ImmoFinder24);`, it does not change anything to the start of the problem (was without setTheme()).

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change your App's theme to DayNight

parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight"

You can also use MaterialComponents' dark theming:

parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight"

And use the system setting (Settings -> Display -> Theme) to enable Dark theme.

Please checkout this link for more information: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/darktheme

Comment: I did that already before. Else it would never have worked with a complete restart (swipe away). I found now `setTheme(R.style.Theme_ImmoFinder24);`, but it is not enough. -> See the update of my post.